# Ajuda com escopo no Javascript

Tags: javascript

O código abaixo serve teoricamente para comparar todos os marcadores do Google Maps API que integrei ao website, onde os marcadores personalizados tem um raio de 750 metros, e estou tentando calcular o raio e saber se eles se sobrepõem, e para isso andei pesquisando na internet e incrementei o código básico da APIv3 e mais o código das funções javascript para o cálculo para verificar se os raios dos marcadores se encontram.

Até a parte da exibição do mapa, os marcadores nos endereços cadastrados na tabela da base de dados (110 total) mais os endereços de reserva de endereços (5 total) foram exibidos, porém no final da **função setMarkers()**; incrementei um **for in** chamando outra função, a **função hasIntersections();**, e aí que que acontece o "erro".

Como sou iniciante em javascript não sei corrigir, no console o erro exibido é, que está na **função hasIntersections();**

> "Uncaught TypeError: circle0.getCenter is not a function"

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
</script>

<script>
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;
var image = 'https://www.keepidea.com.br/painel/assets/images/mark-teste.png';

var locations2 = [['RESERVA: ', -23.9446791, -46.3264323, 'Av. Senador Feijó, 421 - Vila Nova, Santos - SP, 11013-162, Brasil'],['RESERVA: ', , , 'R. Assunção, 414 - Sion, Belo Horizonte - MG, 30320-040, Brasil'],['RESERVA: ', , , 'R. Padre Feijó, 373 - Vila Tiberio, Ribeirão Preto - SP, 14050-360, Brasil'],['RESERVA: ', -23.0654964, -47.2263359, 'R. Vitoriano Salut, 72 - Chácara Belvedere, Indaiatuba - SP, Brasil'],['RESERVA: ', -20.8873894, -47.5997438, 'Rua Ana Luiza, 197 - Bairro Castelo, Batatais - SP, 14300-000, Brasil']];

var locations = [['Vila Osasco', -23.544559, -46.781034, 'Avenida Santo Antônio, 2761, Vila Osasco,  - SP, 06083-215, Brasil'],['Rebouças', -22.8904057, -43.5603237, 'Avenida Rebouças, 3657, Centro,  - SP, 13170-023, Brasil'],['Nutrition Bauru', -22.3370765, -49.0891827, 'Avenida Castelo Branco, 7-15, Vila Independência,  - SP, 17052-000, Brasil'],['Pitangueiras', -23.2022764, -46.8836439, 'Rua Pitangueiras, 790, Jardim Pitangueiras,  - SP, 13206-716, Brasil'],['Vale do Sol', -20.4229151, -49.9592271, 'Avenida pansani, 3092, Vale do sol,  - SP, 15500-302, Brasil'],['Cidade Nova Montes Claros-Mg', -16.739527, -43.8653989, 'Avenida Dona Gregória, 101, Cidade Nova,  - MG, 39400-464, Brasil'],['Centro Salto', -23.199741, -47.3008818, 'Avenida Dom Pedro II, 1421, Centro,  - SP, 13320-241, Brasil'],['ASSIS', -22.6575047, -50.397561, 'Rua Antônio da Silva Cunha Bueno, 425, Jardim Paulista,  - SP, 19815-080, Brasil'],['Paulinia', -22.743178, -47.1744984, 'Avenida João Aranha, 946, Alto de Pinheiros,  - SP, 13145-256, Brasil'],['SBC Centro', -23.7132318, -46.5532384, 'Rua Joaquim Nabuco, 56, Centro,  - SP, 09720-375, Brasil'],['Chácara', -23.6290144, -46.7025941, 'Rua da paz, 1498, Chácara Santo Antônio,  - SP, 04713-000, Brasil'],['Nova Europa', -22.9424831, -47.0573369, 'Avenida Baden Powell, 1831, Nova Europa,  - SP, 13040-093, Brasil'],['Morada do Sol', -23.1269188, -47.244239, 'Rua João Martini, 475, Jardim Morada do Sol,  - SP, 13348-350, Brasil'],['Campo grande RJ', -22.890374, -43.560187, 'Rua do petróleo, 14, Campo Gande,  - RJ, 23087-125, Brasil'],['Tremembé', -23.4587589, -46.6149244, 'Avenida Nova Cantareira, 4794, Tucuruvi,  - SP, 02340-002, Brasil'],['Vila das Belezas', -23.6491279, -46.7543918, 'Estrada de Itapecerica, 2219, Vila das Belezas,  - SP, 05835-005, Brasil'],['CCentro', -23.0854053, -47.2105986, 'Rua Humaitá, 1099, Centro,  - SP, 13339-140, Brasil'],['ITAPECERICA', -23.698334, -46.8527042, 'Rua Ari Batalha, 393, Parque Paraiso,  - SP, 06850-335, Brasil'],['lapa', -23.5250071, -46.6872423, 'Rua Clélia, 911, Lapa,  - SP, 05042-000, Brasil'],['Interação Flamboyant', -17.7718674, -48.6186493, 'Rua B-02, S/N, Estância Itanhanga,  - GO, 75690-000, Brasil'],['Tatuapé', -23.552282, -46.5566401, 'Rua Francisco Marengo, 1717, Tatuapé,  - SP, 03313-001, Brasil'],['Flamboyant', -22.8762222, -47.0358206, 'Rua Comendador Doutor Antônio Pompeo Camargo, 104, Jardim Boa Esperança,  - SP, 13091-502, Brasil'],['N.Sr de Fatima', -22.8975439, -47.1685964, 'Armelinda Espúrio da Silva, 565, Jardim Nossa Senhora de Fátima,  - SP, 13084-450, Brasil'],['Agapeama', -23.2053398, -46.8651296, 'Rua da Varzea Paulista, 487, Vila Agricola,  - SP, 13202-700, Brasil'],['Buriti', -23.2230818, -46.8760877, 'Rua Dom Pedro I, 462, Jardim Buriti,  - SP, 13225-790, Brasil'],['BOA VISTA', -14.8793362, -40.832031, 'Avenida Gilenilda Alves, 1345, Boa Vista,  - BA, 45027-560, Brasil'],['FABRICA DE RESULTADOS', -23.6008617, -46.8988726, 'Rua Pinhal, 83, Jardim Sabia,  - SP, 06716-575, Brasil'],['Valentina Cross Life',-16.7287284, -43.8835938, 'Rua Espírito Santo Esplanada, 395, Esplanada,  - MG, 39401-452, Brasil'],['PEDRO PINHO', -23.5402247, -46.8010548, 'Avenida General Pedro Pinho, 1052, Pestana,  - SP, 06122-160, Brasil']];

function initMap()
{
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-84.568808, -100.418683);
    var options = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        zoom: 4
    });
    marker.setPosition(latlng);
    setMarkers(map,locations);
    setMarkers(map,locations2);
}

Number.prototype.toRadians = function() {
    return this * (Math.PI / 180.0);
};

function distance(lat0, long0, lat1, long1)
{
    var rlat0 = lat0.toRadians();
    var rlong0 = long0.toRadians();
    var rlat1 = lat1.toRadians();
    var rlong1 = long1.toRadians();
    var deltaLat = (rlat1-rlat0);
    var deltaLong = (rlong1-rlong0);
    var a = Math.pow(Math.sin(deltaLat / 2), 2) + Math.pow( Math.sin(deltaLong / 2), 2) * Math.cos(rlat0) * Math.cos(rlat1);  
    return (2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a))) * 6378137;
}

function hasIntersections(circle0,circle1)
{
    var center0 = circle0.getCenter();
    var center1 = circle1.getCenter();
    var maxDist = circle0.getRadius()+circle1.getRadius();
    var actualDist = distance(center0.lat(),center0.lng(),center1.lat(),center1.lng());
    return maxDist>=actualDist;
}

circles = [];
circles2 = [];
circle = null;
circle2 = null;

function setMarkers(map,locations)
{

    var marker = null;
    var i = null;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
    {
        var loan = locations[i][0]
        var lat = locations[i][1]
        var long = locations[i][2]
        var add =  locations[i][3]
        latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
            map: map,
            title: loan,
            position: latlngset,
            icon: image
        });

        var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
            radius: 750,
            strokeColor: "#818c99",
            fillColor: "#ffffff",
            fillOpacity: 0.50
        });

        circles.push(cityCircle);

        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        var content = "<h5>" + loan + '</h5>' + "<strong>Endereço:</strong> " + add;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
            return function()
            {
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            };
        })(marker,content,infowindow));

    }

    var marker = null;
    var i = null;

    for (i = 0; i < locations2.length; i++)
    {
        var loan = locations2[i][0]
        var lat = locations2[i][1]
        var long = locations2[i][2]
        var add =  locations2[i][3]
        latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
            map: map,
            title: loan,
            position: latlngset,
            icon: image
        });

        var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
            radius: 750,
            strokeColor: "#229A1F",
            fillColor: "#49DA45",
            fillOpacity: 0.50
        });

        circles2.push(cityCircle);

        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        var content = "<h5>" + loan + '</h5>' + "<strong>Endereço:</strong> " + add;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            };
        })(marker,content,infowindow));
    }

    for ( var circle1 in circles )
    {
        for ( var circle2 in circles2 )
        {
            console.log(hasIntersections(circle1, circle2)); 
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Fiz um teste no console, com console.log(circles), e o resultado foi no total de 5 resultados como:

> _.qg {gm_accessors_: {…}, map: gg, gm_bindings_: {…}, zoom: 4, center: _.L, …} A :
>   *.Rw {Ck: 0, **e3***: {…}, b: "planetRadius", f: false, getPlanetRadius: ƒ, …} center :
>   _.L {lat: ƒ, lng: ƒ} closure_uid_660309532 : 1199 draggable_changed : ƒ c() editable_changed : ƒ e() f : gg {gm_bindings_: {…}, __gm: Cf,
>   gm_accessors_: {…}, zoom: 4, center: _.L, …} fillColor : "#49DA45"
>   fillOpacity :
>   0.5 gm_accessors_ : {map: null, zoom: null, center: null, radius: null, strokeColor: null, …} gm_bindings_ : {map: {…}, zoom: {…},
>   center: {…}, radius: {…}, strokeColor: {…}, …} hh : hW {Ck: 0, __e3_:
>   {…}, b: _.sg, gm_bindings_: {…}, gm_accessors_: {…}, …} ja : (9) [Mc,
>   Mc, Mc, Mc, Mc, Mc, Mc, Mc, Mc] map : gg {gm_bindings_: {…}, __gm: Cf,
>   gm_accessors_: {…}, zoom: 4, center: _.L, …} radius : 750 strokeColor
>   : "#229A1F" vh : (3) [Mc, Mc, Mc] visible : true zoom : 4
>   __e3_ : {toolbar: {…}, mouseover: {…}, click: {…}, mouseout: {…}}
>   __proto : Object

E para console.log(circles2) o resultado no total de 110, para circles e circles2 os valores batem, pois para var location[] tem 109 e var location[] tem 5, total de 115, o que tem cadastrado no banco de dados.

Comment: Já verificou, por acaso, quais são os valores de `circle1` e `circle2` que você passou por parâmetro para `hasIntersections`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Incrementei o resultado das arrays e abaixo do código javascript um dos resultados do console.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o código no final da função alterando o **for in** para **for of** na função setMarkers() com a ajuda da comunidade **SO_EN**;

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
</script>

<script>
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;
var image = 'https://www.keepidea.com.br/painel/assets/images/mark-teste.png';

var locations2 = [['RESERVA: ', -23.9446791, -46.3264323, 'Av. Senador Feijó, 421 - Vila Nova, Santos - SP, 11013-162, Brasil'],['RESERVA: ', , , 'R. Assunção, 414 - Sion, Belo Horizonte - MG, 30320-040, Brasil'],['RESERVA: ', , , 'R. Padre Feijó, 373 - Vila Tiberio, Ribeirão Preto - SP, 14050-360, Brasil'],['RESERVA: ', -23.0654964, -47.2263359, 'R. Vitoriano Salut, 72 - Chácara Belvedere, Indaiatuba - SP, Brasil'],['RESERVA: ', -20.8873894, -47.5997438, 'Rua Ana Luiza, 197 - Bairro Castelo, Batatais - SP, 14300-000, Brasil']];

var locations = [['Vila Osasco', -23.544559, -46.781034, 'Avenida Santo Antônio, 2761, Vila Osasco,  - SP, 06083-215, Brasil'],['Rebouças', -22.8904057, -43.5603237, 'Avenida Rebouças, 3657, Centro,  - SP, 13170-023, Brasil'],['Nutrition Bauru', -22.3370765, -49.0891827, 'Avenida Castelo Branco, 7-15, Vila Independência,  - SP, 17052-000, Brasil'],['Pitangueiras', -23.2022764, -46.8836439, 'Rua Pitangueiras, 790, Jardim Pitangueiras,  - SP, 13206-716, Brasil'],['Vale do Sol', -20.4229151, -49.9592271, 'Avenida pansani, 3092, Vale do sol,  - SP, 15500-302, Brasil'],['Cidade Nova Montes Claros-Mg', -16.739527, -43.8653989, 'Avenida Dona Gregória, 101, Cidade Nova,  - MG, 39400-464, Brasil'],['Centro Salto', -23.199741, -47.3008818, 'Avenida Dom Pedro II, 1421, Centro,  - SP, 13320-241, Brasil'],['ASSIS', -22.6575047, -50.397561, 'Rua Antônio da Silva Cunha Bueno, 425, Jardim Paulista,  - SP, 19815-080, Brasil'],['Paulinia', -22.743178, -47.1744984, 'Avenida João Aranha, 946, Alto de Pinheiros,  - SP, 13145-256, Brasil'],['SBC Centro', -23.7132318, -46.5532384, 'Rua Joaquim Nabuco, 56, Centro,  - SP, 09720-375, Brasil'],['Chácara', -23.6290144, -46.7025941, 'Rua da paz, 1498, Chácara Santo Antônio,  - SP, 04713-000, Brasil'],['Nova Europa', -22.9424831, -47.0573369, 'Avenida Baden Powell, 1831, Nova Europa,  - SP, 13040-093, Brasil'],['Morada do Sol', -23.1269188, -47.244239, 'Rua João Martini, 475, Jardim Morada do Sol,  - SP, 13348-350, Brasil'],['Campo grande RJ', -22.890374, -43.560187, 'Rua do petróleo, 14, Campo Gande,  - RJ, 23087-125, Brasil'],['Tremembé', -23.4587589, -46.6149244, 'Avenida Nova Cantareira, 4794, Tucuruvi,  - SP, 02340-002, Brasil'],['Vila das Belezas', -23.6491279, -46.7543918, 'Estrada de Itapecerica, 2219, Vila das Belezas,  - SP, 05835-005, Brasil'],['CCentro', -23.0854053, -47.2105986, 'Rua Humaitá, 1099, Centro,  - SP, 13339-140, Brasil'],['ITAPECERICA', -23.698334, -46.8527042, 'Rua Ari Batalha, 393, Parque Paraiso,  - SP, 06850-335, Brasil'],['lapa', -23.5250071, -46.6872423, 'Rua Clélia, 911, Lapa,  - SP, 05042-000, Brasil'],['Interação Flamboyant', -17.7718674, -48.6186493, 'Rua B-02, S/N, Estância Itanhanga,  - GO, 75690-000, Brasil'],['Tatuapé', -23.552282, -46.5566401, 'Rua Francisco Marengo, 1717, Tatuapé,  - SP, 03313-001, Brasil'],['Flamboyant', -22.8762222, -47.0358206, 'Rua Comendador Doutor Antônio Pompeo Camargo, 104, Jardim Boa Esperança,  - SP, 13091-502, Brasil'],['N.Sr de Fatima', -22.8975439, -47.1685964, 'Armelinda Espúrio da Silva, 565, Jardim Nossa Senhora de Fátima,  - SP, 13084-450, Brasil'],['Agapeama', -23.2053398, -46.8651296, 'Rua da Varzea Paulista, 487, Vila Agricola,  - SP, 13202-700, Brasil'],['Buriti', -23.2230818, -46.8760877, 'Rua Dom Pedro I, 462, Jardim Buriti,  - SP, 13225-790, Brasil'],['BOA VISTA', -14.8793362, -40.832031, 'Avenida Gilenilda Alves, 1345, Boa Vista,  - BA, 45027-560, Brasil'],['FABRICA DE RESULTADOS', -23.6008617, -46.8988726, 'Rua Pinhal, 83, Jardim Sabia,  - SP, 06716-575, Brasil'],['Valentina Cross Life',-16.7287284, -43.8835938, 'Rua Espírito Santo Esplanada, 395, Esplanada,  - MG, 39401-452, Brasil'],['PEDRO PINHO', -23.5402247, -46.8010548, 'Avenida General Pedro Pinho, 1052, Pestana,  - SP, 06122-160, Brasil']];

function initMap()
{
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-84.568808, -100.418683);
    var options = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        zoom: 4
    });
    marker.setPosition(latlng);
    setMarkers(map,locations);
    setMarkers(map,locations2);
}

Number.prototype.toRadians = function() {
    return this * (Math.PI / 180.0);
};

function distance(lat0, long0, lat1, long1)
{
    var rlat0 = lat0.toRadians();
    var rlong0 = long0.toRadians();
    var rlat1 = lat1.toRadians();
    var rlong1 = long1.toRadians();
    var deltaLat = (rlat1-rlat0);
    var deltaLong = (rlong1-rlong0);
    var a = Math.pow(Math.sin(deltaLat / 2), 2) + Math.pow( Math.sin(deltaLong / 2), 2) * Math.cos(rlat0) * Math.cos(rlat1);  
    return (2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a))) * 6378137;
}

function hasIntersections(circle0,circle1)
{
    var center0 = circle0.getCenter();
    var center1 = circle1.getCenter();
    var maxDist = circle0.getRadius()+circle1.getRadius();
    var actualDist = distance(center0.lat(),center0.lng(),center1.lat(),center1.lng());
    return maxDist>=actualDist;
}

circles = [];
circles2 = [];
circle = null;
circle2 = null;

function setMarkers(map,locations)
{

    var marker = null;
    var i = null;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
    {
        var loan = locations[i][0]
        var lat = locations[i][1]
        var long = locations[i][2]
        var add =  locations[i][3]
        latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
            map: map,
            title: loan,
            position: latlngset,
            icon: image
        });

        var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
            radius: 750,
            strokeColor: "#818c99",
            fillColor: "#ffffff",
            fillOpacity: 0.50
        });

        circles.push(cityCircle);

        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        var content = "<h5>" + loan + '</h5>' + "<strong>Endereço:</strong> " + add;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
            return function()
            {
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            };
        })(marker,content,infowindow));

    }

    var marker = null;
    var i = null;

    for (i = 0; i < locations2.length; i++)
    {
        var loan = locations2[i][0]
        var lat = locations2[i][1]
        var long = locations2[i][2]
        var add =  locations2[i][3]
        latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
            map: map,
            title: loan,
            position: latlngset,
            icon: image
        });

        var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
            radius: 750,
            strokeColor: "#229A1F",
            fillColor: "#49DA45",
            fillOpacity: 0.50
        });

        circles2.push(cityCircle);

        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        var content = "<h5>" + loan + '</h5>' + "<strong>Endereço:</strong> " + add;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            };
        })(marker,content,infowindow));
    }

    for ( var circle1 of circles )
    {
        for ( var circle2 of circles2 )
        {
            console.log(hasIntersections(circle1, circle2)); 
        }
    }
}
</script>
```